# A question on exponential increasing sequences of natural numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request

Let $(a_i)$ be an exponential increasing sequences of natural numbers; there are constants $a\in(1,2)$, $b>0$ such that $|a_{i}-ba^i|$ is exponentially decreasing. Let $(s_{k})$ be a sequences in $\{-1,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ such that 
$\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}a_{i}\not=0$ for all $n$. I try to prove that there is a constant $c>0$ such that $|\sum_{i=1}^{n}s_{i}a_{i}|\ge ca_{n}$ for all $n$. For the Fibonacci sequence and some other I suceed, but in general I got into some mess. Is this problen known and is it solved?

Comment: If I understand the situation correctly, powers of 2 is a sequence which fits your conditions and will not give you your conclusion.  Also, if the sequence approximates ba^i but not equal to it, can you say something about b and a to guarantee the exponential decrease in error?  Gerhard "Real Approach Seems Naturally Better" Paseman, 2016.11.23.

Comment: Sorry, I thought about growthrate in (1,2). Known examples of such sequences are given by the nearest integers of powers of Pisot numbers.

Comment: Your condition implies that $a$ is a Pisot number. This is a theorem of Salem.

Comment: Dear Anthony: Ok, assume that a is a Pisot numbers. Is the implication correct? Where can I find the proof?

Comment: I am not quite sure about your quantifiers. What is $n$ when you say for all $m$ with $1\le m\le n$?

Comment: I meant:  There is a constant c>0 depending on $(a_{i})$ and $(s_{i})$ sucht that for all $n$ the implication holds

Comment: I edited the question to make the quantifiers obvious.

Comment: When you say that those partial sums aren't 0, is that condition supposed to hold for all sequences $s$?  Or do you mean "if a particular $\pm 1$ sequence satisfies this for all $n,$ then that also satisfies that lower bound?"  And do you want $c$ to be independent of $s$?

Comment: I mean "if a particular ±1 sequence satisfies this for all n, then that also satisfies that lower bound" and $c$ may depent on $(s_{i})$

Comment: As for me, this doesn't look true for the Fibonacci numbers. Check out the sequence $(s_i)$ starting with 1 and after that repeating the pattern $1,1,-1$ (so it starts wth $1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,1,-1,\dots$)...